# View не правильно позицируется

Tags: android

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:background="@drawable/login_faggot">

<TextView
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Welcome."
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
<TextView
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/grayBg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/plsLogin"
    android:text="Please Login."
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editLogin"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editPass"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editLogin"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
<TextView
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
<EditText
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_white_24dp"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/user_name"
    android:id="@+id/editLogin"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/plsLogin"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"/>
<EditText
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_white_24dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:id="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editLogin"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:text="Remember Me"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editPass"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editPass"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editPass"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/radioButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/ProgressBar"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему Кнопка Login Поверх FrameLayout? Как исправить эту ситуацию. FrameLayout должен быть поверх всех окон

Comment: Короче бага в том что я используя Button что - то с енй не то случилось после обновы. Если использовать TextVIew то все норм работает. 
Что мне надо изменить в Build чтобы перейти обратно в API 25 Хотя бы. Там багов небыло

Comment: это не бага - это фича =) в 25 у вас тоже так же должно получиться...

Comment: Мужики жизнь боль =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте атрибут `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` у кнопки.

Начиная с  **API Level 21 (Android 5.0 Lollipop)**, кнопки имеют высоту по умолчанию, которая заставляет их всегда отрисовываться поверх всего. Стиль `Button` по умолчанию в *Material* имеет `StateListAnimator`, который управляет свойствами `android:elevation` и `android:translationZ`.

Comment: А почему такое происходит только в Button? в TextVIew допустим такого нету.